# Installing Libraries for Idle Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, module, python-idle

My question is very simple and very inexperimented. So, I need to use the module lxml on Python.
Though I have been able to install it successfully via the command prompt and can execute my programs from there, I can't seem to do it on the environnement I usually use: Idle.

So I have no idea how to be able to use the modules from lxml (or any module that is not in the standard library for that matter) on my Idle on Windows.

Comment: Could you give the Python version(s) you are using in each environment?

Comment: On Idle I have python 3.8 32-bits and when I run on the cmd it's python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

'IDLE' is a package of about 60 modules in Lib/idlelib.  When you run IDLE with python x.y, the code you enter into either the editor or shell is handed back to python x.y (running in a separate process).  To use lxml in code you enter into IDLE, you can either run IDLE with 3.7, which on your machine has lxml installed,

```
> py -3.7 -m idlelib
```

or install lxml into python 3.8

```
> py -3.8 -m pip install lxml
```

The above are Command Prompt entries.  If `pip` was not installed with 3.8, run

```
> py -3.8 -m ensurepip
```

According to [this page](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/), lxml is available for 3.8.

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thanks a lot! Damn, I have a loooot to learn.